# Calculating simple probabilities of events with multiple unions and intersections:

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I need to calculate $\Pr(A)$ in the following cases:

1. $A = B \cap C \cap D$ and $B, C, D$ are independent events
2. $A = (B \cup C) \cap (D \cup C)$ and $B, C, D, E$ are independent events
3. $A = (B \cap C) \cup (D \cap C)$ with $(B \cap C)\cap (D \cap C) = \varnothing$ and B, C, D, E are independent events'}
4. $A = (B \cap C) \cup (D \cap C)$ and $(B \cap C)\cap (D \cap C) \neq \varnothing$ and $B, C, D, E$ are independent events.''}
5. $A = B \cup C \cup D$ und $B, C, D$ are NOT NESCESSARILY independent events.

---

Progress so far:

Here are some solutions I came up with. I realize that the notation is a little untidy/the simplifications have been inconsistently applied. I would greatly appreciate any feedback.

Task 1:
$$ \Pr(A) = \Pr(B) \cdot \Pr(C) \cdot \Pr(D) $$

Task 2:
\begin{align*}
\Pr(A) &= \big(\Pr(B) + \Pr(C) - \Pr(B \cap C) \big) \cap \big( \Pr(D) + \Pr(C) - \Pr(C \cap D)\big) \\
&= \big(\Pr(B) + \Pr(C) - \Pr(B \cap C) \big) \cdot \big( \Pr(D) + \Pr(C) - \Pr(C \cap D)\big)
\end{align*}

Task 3:
\begin{align*}
\Pr(A) &= \Pr(B \cap C) + \Pr(D \cap C) + \Pr\big( (B \cap C) \cap (D \cap C) \big) \\
&= \Pr(B \cap C) + \Pr(D \cap C) + 0 \\
&= \Pr(B \cap C) + \Pr(D \cap C) \\
&= \Pr(B) \cdot \Pr(C) + \Pr(D) \cdot \Pr(C) \\
&= \Pr(C) \cdot \big( \Pr(B) + \Pr(D) \big) 
\end{align*}

Task 4:
\begin{align*}
\Pr(A) &= \Pr(B \cap C) + \Pr(D \cap C) + \Pr\big( (B \cap C) \cap (D \cap C) \big) \\
&= \Pr(C) \cdot \big( \Pr(B) + \Pr(D) \big) + \Pr\big( (B \cap C) \cap (D \cap C) \big) \\
&= \Pr(C) \cdot \big( \Pr(B) + \Pr(D) \big) + \big( (\Pr(B) \cdot \Pr(C)) \cdot (\Pr(D) \cdot \Pr(C) \big) \\
&= \Pr(C) \cdot \big( \Pr(B) + \Pr(D) \big) + \Pr(C)^2 \cdot \Pr(B) \cdot \Pr(D) \\
&= \Pr(C) \cdot \big( \Pr(B) + \Pr(D) + \Pr(C) \cdot \Pr(B) \cdot \Pr(D) \big)
\end{align*}

Task 5:
$$ \Pr(A) = \Pr(B) + \Pr(C) + \Pr(D) - \Pr(B \cap C) - \Pr(B \cap D) - \Pr(C \cap D) + \Pr(B \cap C \cap D)$$

Comment: Surely you have some typos... $(B\cup C)\cap (D\cup C)$ shouldn't that final $C$ be an $E$ instead?  Else why even mention $E$ in the following sentence?  You hvae some errors in your attempts, I see for example $(Pr(B)+Pr(C)-Pr(B\cap C))\color{red}{\cap}(Pr(D)\cdots)$  intersection is used for sets and events but the objects inside of those parentheses are numbers.

Comment: @JMoravitz Interesting. Such are the perils of blindly copying tasks. Strangely enough, I have not made any typos, the task actually appeared that way. 

As for the errors in the attempts, would you mind elaborating a little further?

Also, I am not sure how to interpret " intersection is used for sets and events but the objects inside of those parentheses are numbers"

Comment: You can talk about $A\cap B$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets, but you cannot talk about $5\cap 12$ as it is meaningless (*unless you want to be incredibly pedantic and interpret the numbers as dedekind cuts or the like*)

Comment: Even if you were to apply your supposed properties in the other order, breaking it apart as multiplication first before breaking it apart via inclusion-exclusion, that assumes that given $B,C,D$ independent that $(B\cup C)$ is independent of $(D\cup C)$ which I am rather certain is false (*consider $B,D$ both as the impossible event*).  Replacing the second $C$ with an $E$ instead, it might be true but I haven't personally seen or written a proof for it and so would have avoided breaking it down like that.

Comment: In the fourth task you have $Pr((B\cap C)\cap (D\cap C))=Pr(B)\cdot Pr(C)\cdot Pr(D)\cdot Pr(C)$ but this is incorrect since $C$ is not independent from $C$ (*unless it is either the sure event or the impossible event*).  Notice that $B\cap C\cap D\cap C = B\cap C\cap D$.  Again, this should have been a non issue if the second $C$ were replaced by an $E$ as likely intended.  Note $Pr(C)=Pr(C\cap C) \neq Pr(C)\cdot Pr(C)$ again unless $Pr(C)=1$ or $0$.

Comment: @JMoravitz many thanks. So, if I understand, then it would be safe so far to conclude that task 1 is fine, task 2 contains a semantic error, task 3 is fine, task 4 has been obfuscated by the E problem and task 5 is fine?